# I made my own custom stack and want to know how is there a way to iterate through the stack in reverse

Tags: c++

This is the interface file

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACH_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
    struct StackFrame{
        char data;
        StackFrame* next;
    };
    StackFrame* head;
public:
    Stack();
    void push(char);
    char pop();
    void empty();
    bool check_empty();
    void print();
    //Note:This code prints the data in stack format !!!
    ~Stack();
};



#endif // !STACK_H
```

This is the implementation file

```
#include "Stack.h"

Stack::Stack():head(nullptr){}

void Stack::push(char c)
{
    StackFrame* temp = new  StackFrame;
    temp->data = c;
    temp->next = nullptr;

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

char Stack::pop()
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "There is nothing in the stack to pop at the moment!!!" << endl;
        return '\0';
    }

    StackFrame* holder = head;
    char temp_chr = holder->data;

    head = head->next;
    free(holder);
    holder = nullptr;

    return temp_chr;
}

void Stack::empty()
{
    StackFrame* holder;
    while(head!=nullptr)
    {
        holder = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(holder);
    }
    holder = nullptr;
    head = nullptr;
}

bool Stack::check_empty()
{
    return head==nullptr;
}

void Stack::print() {
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "Nothing in stack at the moment :( " << endl;
        return;
    }

    StackFrame* holder = head;
    while (holder != nullptr)
    {
        cout << holder->data;
        holder = holder->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    empty();
}
```

This is the application file

```
#include"Stack.h"
#include<string>

int main()
{
    int num;
    string push;
    Stack st;
    cout << "Enter your name = ";
    getline(cin, push);
    for (int i = 0; i < push.length(); i++)
    {
        st.push(push[i]);
    }
    st.print();

    cout << "How many times do you want to pop? = ";
    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        st.pop();
    }
    st.print();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can someone help me out on how to reverse iterate in this stack class which i made myself using the concept of linked list, i googled a bit and got the gist of things to use **tail** , Can someone elaborate another way if possible please or share a link to a site. It will help me out later a lot when i start working on binary trees and if i ever need to reverse iterate in the binary tree nodes.

Comment: This won't help you much, but the point of a stack is you only get to interact with the top-most element. If you can iterate it, it's not a stack.

Comment: The real advice is to not use that kind stack if you want to iterate in both directions (unless you want to challenge yourself and write the program in the most counter productive way possible). Although, if you really want to, you can iterate over this stack normally while storing the results in a second stack and then iterate over the second one which would give you the reverse order.

Comment: Unrelated: not a bad list implementation, but watch out for `free(holder);`. You can't safely `free` something you allocated with `new`. You have to `delete` it. `free` is paired with `malloc` and the *alloc` family and `new[]` is paired with `delete[]`

Comment: You make a second stack.  Pop everything off the first stack pushing it on the second stack.  One-by-one pop everything off the second stack, do whatever else you want for the iteration (e.g., print it), and then push it back onto the first stack.

Comment: @user4581301 Saying that stack which allows iteration is not a stack is like saying that if a plane can also swim on water, it's not a plane. Iteration is not in any way mandatory but it's a nice feature useful in some situations, especially if it is implemented in a way that doesn't increase complexity of the stack.

Comment: Ok noted I'll use delete instead of free()

Comment: I actually recently moved from C to C++ so i have a habit of free() and malloc() but ill try to use new and delete as you stated , other than that i am looking for a way to reverse iterate without using a second stack.

Comment: You could add the `tail` to the implementation. Then, every node would need a link to its previous node. But at that point, you have a doubly-linked list, not a stack.

Comment: @PajLe exactly my thoughts , that was what my initial idea was but later realized i would not be making a stack anymore but still thanks for the tip

Comment: Well, you could implement stack on an array. Pushing would not be O(1), unless you want to have hard limit on the size, but reverse iteration would be trivial.

Comment: Hmm... I did at first think of making it on an array but later didn't implement it but now ill look into it thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as mentioned above, stack is LIFO data structure and thus should use another data structure for that purpose.

Second, you can use second stack and copy data over to new stack, which is expensive.

Third option would be to go from the top and kip a track and store pointer to the previous node and to the pointer that point to the previous of previous node. Something like this:

```
struct reverseStack {
    StackFrame* node;
    reverseStack* previousPointer;

    reverseStack (StackFrame* n, ReverseStack* p) :
        node (n), previousPointer(p) { }
}
```

than using simple for loop you create pointer to the top, and go to the next and store that info into this structure. In your code you have something like this:

```
reverseStack top (nullptr, topFrame);
StackFrame currentFrame = top->next();
ReverseStack current; = top;
while (currentFrame != nullptr) {
    // alghoritm for linking previous nodes.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a second Stack object rather than a second list.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive algorithm would have worked fine (use the recursive call stack as your "reverse" stack).

```
void Stack::print(StackFrame *pCurr) {
    if (pCurr != nullptr)
        {
        print(pCurr->Next);
        cout << pCurr->ch;
        }
    }

void Stack::print() {
    if (head == nullptr)
        {
        cerr << "Nothing in stack at the moment :( " << endl;
        return;
        }
    print(head);
    cout << endl;
    }
```